Expo Go se conecta bien con Firebase - Firestore - Pero cuando compilo aunque el usuario se autentique no conecta con firestore
Problema de lectura de datos en Firestore en AAB generado con EAS Build
Descripción del problema: #
Estoy desarrollando una aplicación con Expo que utiliza Firebase para la autenticación y Firestore para el almacenamiento de datos. La aplicación funciona correctamente en Expo Go, incluyendo la autenticación y la lectura/escritura de datos en Firestore. Sin embargo, cuando compilo un AAB con EAS Build y lo instalo en un dispositivo Android, la autenticación funciona, pero la lectura de datos de Firestore falla silenciosamente (sin generar errores visibles en los registros).
Pasos que he tomado:
He verificado y corregido la configuración de Firebase en mi proyecto y en EAS Build.
He revisado y ajustado las reglas de seguridad de Firestore para asegurarme de que permiten las operaciones de lectura necesarias.
He desactivado la ofuscación de código (ProGuard/R8) para descartarla como posible causa del problema.
He configurado correctamente mi app.json para EAS Build, eliminando las propiedades nativas innecesarias.
He verificado que las credenciales de Android en EAS Build coinciden con las de Play Console y que las huellas digitales SHA-1 coinciden con las de Firebase.
He comprobado los permisos de internet y la configuración de red en mi AndroidManifest.xml.
He investigado posibles problemas de compatibilidad con bibliotecas específicas y he actualizado algunas de ellas.
He agregado registros detallados en mi código para intentar identificar el problema, pero no he encontrado errores evidentes.
Información adicional:
Expo SDK versión: 51.0.31
Firebase versión: 10.13.1
EAS CLI versión: 13.16.0
Estoy compilando solo para Android.
No estoy utilizando variables de entorno ni archivos .env.
¿Alguien ha experimentado un problema similar o tiene alguna idea de qué podría estar causando este problema y cómo solucionarlo?
Cualquier ayuda o sugerencia será muy apreciada. ¡Gracias de antemano!

¿Has hecho pruebas en fase de desarrollo? Si las has hecho, ¿qué resultados has obtenido? La mejor opción es siempre probar en desarrollo, antes de generar cualquier archivo final.

Hola amigo, muchas gracias por tu respuesta. En Desarrollo también pasa lo mismo. Solo funciona en Expo Go.

Pues en desarrollo, revisa el Logcat, allí debe haber alguna indicación del motivo del fallo. Si no encuentras nada, pon puntos de interrupción en la parte donde debe ocurrir la conexión con Firestore y revisa el estado de las variables o eventuales mensajes de error que puedan estar siendo capturados, pero no informados al usuario.

Por si no sabes a qué me refiero con poner puntos de interrupción, me refiero a hacer clic en la barra de la izquierda de aquella línea de código donde quieres parar. Cuando ejecutas un  debug del programa el mismo se detendrá ahí y podrás revisar el estado de las variables en ese punto. Es una herramienta utilísima para determinar problemas en el código. Por ciero, no dices en que IDE estás programando, así que no te puedo dar más detalles sobre cómo depurar adecuadamente tu código.

Hola, estoy trabajando en VsCode. Escucho cualquier recomendación
